# how to get devices connected to same wifi network in ionic4?

Tags: javascript, typescript, networking, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am developing an app in the `ionic4 framework`.
I need to get devices that are connected to my **wifi network** or the **same wifi network** i.e. `IP address`, `device name` etc.

I have searched for any tutorial online, but couldn't find any.

Could somebody guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) buddy. I'm not sure whether it is possible with ionic. There are ways to connect your device with wifi networks, there are ways to get network information but this may be bit tough. Although this feature was added to ionic plugin request list. If you want to connect with some other devices, you can use [BluetoothLE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le) plugin. You can use that plugin to get a list of active Bluetooth devices and connect with them.

Hope this [thread](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1599) will help you.
Also follow [this](https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard).